# Demystify Transaction signing process

Tags: security, signature

Can someone explain in layman term, why the transaction needs to be signed and the role of public key, private key in transaction signing process. 
From what I have read so far:

1. When user creates a new Account, specifies passphrase. Privatekey is
   generated and stored in keystore file. (encrypted using passphrase).
2. When sending transaction, Passphrase is used to decrypt the keystore and retrieve private key.
3. Private key is used to sign transaction. Signed transaction is published by the node.
4. Receiving node uses public key (how other nodes get public key?) to verify
   signature. If valid, transaction is processed.

Pls let me know if above understanding is correct and help to understand questions raised in the workflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is basically correct. In (4), any node can receive a transaction, check the signature and relay it to other nodes.

The public key can be recovered from the signature, so it doesn't need to be passed around or looked up from anywhere. (This is different from Bitcoin, which wastes bandwidth by passing public keys around in spending transactions; Satoshi doesn't seem to have been that deep into cryptography.)

Comment: How does this process work for transactions sent by a contract? (e.g. one contract calling a method on another contract) as far as I know creating a contract doesn't involve passphrases/private keys. If tx's sent by contract are undistinguished from tx's sent by an "account" how are they actually signed/verified?

Comment: @jlpiedrahita See this answer
http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11252/smart-contract-transaction-signature/11266#11266

Comment: excellent clarification, I knew I had missed some key part in all of this, thanks a lot.

Comment: this answer does not explain what data is used to sign the transaction. Is extradata involved in signing process for example?

Comment: @Nulik all the data in the transaction is signed. See here for what data is in a transaction: https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f IIUC "extradata" is a field of a block, not a transaction. A transaction has a "data" field, and this is part of the payload that is signed.

Comment: How does "the public key can be recovered from the signature"? Is there any documentation related to that? @Edmund Edgar

Comment: @Alper for example see the implementation in https://github.com/ethereum/eth-keys#keyapiecdsa_recovermessage_hash-signature---publickey